# How to make Jframe button open another Jframe screen in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a Jframe and i need to link it to another Jframe if button is clicked it goes to another Jframe screen on click and closes old screen. accully i want if user click login register then it goes to login screen for getting login i am newbie and a bigginner kindly help me P.S its my first Qestion at Stack so ignore mistakes.

Comment: If you built your form with the NetBeans Form Designer then right-click on your JButton and from the popup menu select **Events -- Action -- actionPerformed**. The event will be created and NetBeans will open the code window. Add this code into that event: `this.setVisible(false); new FrmMain().setVisible(true);` as [DJ_Entertainment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11682305/dj-entertainment) has already provided to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double Click the Register Button in the NETBEANS or add the Event Listener on Click Event (ActionListener)

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.setVisible(false);
        new FrmMain().setVisible(true); // Main Form to show after the Login Form..
    }
});
```

Comment: you are really helpful